# Sum costs for the last 12 months MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access database form, and I want to sum the total costs for the field [Cost], but only for the last 12 months. I have a date field as well, which is the full date of the record, e.g. 25/09/2020.

If possible I would want to exclude any months that have yet to end. For example if it is mid September, I would want September to be excluded. This is not a requirement, just something that would be nice to have.

To further explain, I already have a total sum for all records, but I want another one that just shows the last 12 months. I don't want to specify the date range manually, like 01/01/2020 to 01/01/2021. I want to automatically sum the last 12 months of records, which would update as soon as a new record is added / or when a new month is started if the incomplete month is excluded.

I don't want to use a report to do this as that would mean opening a different page, which if it has to be that way the users would never check the totals.

I also have no clue how to use SQL so if it can be done with normal VBA code that would be amazing.

Edit. I now have the code used in the accepted answer and it works fine now. I could not for the life of me work out how to make it sum for a date range. The only issue is that it doesnt automatically update, but I can live with that. As long it it shows up when the form opens it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try on below expression of data source of a textbox.

```
=DSum("[Cost]","[Table1]","[cDate]>=#" & DateAdd("m",-12,Date()) & "# AND [cDate]<=#" & Date() & "#")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, does what I need it to do now. Couldn't work out how I was supposed to specify a date range other than stating specific dates.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try somthing like this:

1. For cost only:

```
SELECT SUM(yt.Cost) AS SumOfCost
FROM YourTable yt
WHERE yt.DateField BETWEEN DATESERIAL(YEAR(Date), 1, 1) 
    AND DATESERIAL(YEAR(Date), MONTH(yt.DateField), 1-1)
```

2. For cost and month ;)

```
SELECT FORMAT(yt.DateField, "yyyy-MMM") As CMonth, SUM(yt.Cost) AS SumOfCost
FROM YourTable yt
WHERE yt.DateField BETWEEN DATESERIAL(YEAR(Date), 1, 1) 
    AND DATESERIAL(YEAR(Date), MONTH(yt.DateField), 1-1)
GROUP BY FORMAT(yt.DateField, "yyyy-MMM")
```

Note:

`DateSerial(Year(Date()), 1, 1)` returns 1. January of this year based on today's date :)

`DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)` returns last day of previous month based on today's date :)

For further details, please see: [DateSerial Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dateserial-function-a0128476-83a0-407c-831a-93f2b046f503)